# Dynamically replace data inside a div container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

What is the best way to load data dynamically inside a DIV container?

Let's say I have a number of pictures on a page. Clicking a picture opens a DIV container on the screen (no page refresh) which contains all comments for that image.

At the moment I am sending an AJAX request to load comments from the DB and echo them out in another page. I am then appending that data, with jQuery, inside the DIV container. Clicking on another image clears the container and new data is loaded vie new AJAX request.

It just seems to me that this might not be the most efficient way of doing it, because if the user is going back and forth clicking on images on the page, then data has to be reloaded every single time.

I see that facebook changes the URL every time when a new image is selected. So may be they use an ID from the URL to load the data without sending an AJAX request?

May be once data is loaded and another image is selected, it will be better to just hide the old image comments on the page rather than discard them ? So that if the image is clicked again, it will not be required to reload its data?

Comment: It is  better to load all the data in one go and hide unnecessary data.And display those on some event you require.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an idea as to how you may avoid making frequent/duplicate ajax requests for the same image.

Say you've a function to draw comments in your div that acepts the reponse from the server, such as:

```
function displayComments(resp) {
    //Do stuff
}
```

And let's assume an ajax call on image click looks like the following.

```
//We're probably better of using the wrapper (class/ID) of images to
//delegate events since setting/unsetting data may cause problems
//if we'd used bind on images directly
$("imagesContainerSelector").on("click", "img", function() {

    var $this = $(this);

    //See if comments have already been fetched previously.
    //If yes, we'd have stored them as that image's data and 
    //we'd now simply use that data to display the comments.
    if ( $this.data("comments") ) {

        displayComments($this.data("comments"));
    } else {
        //We've not fetched comments for this image yet, so, fetch it
        $.ajax({
            url: '...',
            data: '...'
            //more options
        }).done(function(data) {
            //When done, display comments
            displayComments(data);
            //Set the resp as data for later use
            $this.data("comments", data);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like a good approach. How would you store the incoming data? 2 dimensional array? How will the data() function look like?

Comment: Store the data as it comes from the server, or whatever you want to store. [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) is a built-in jQuery method to store arbitrary data.

Comment: Thanks man. The .data() function has to be attached to a div element? And it will essentially store my whole comments data in "data-x" attribute of that element, which is not visible on the DOM?

Comment: What about performance - is that approach faster than making a duplicated ajax call ?

Comment: Yes, `data-*` set via the `.data()` will be stored in the memory and not visible in the DOM. Of course, this is way faster than hitting your server for no reason!

Answer (score 0):

If you respecify the < img >-Tag inside some div so the pictures get loaded after you do that. If you specify the same picture twice or more times, the image is already in the cache of most browsers. Thatwhy you can just do something like

$('#divid').html(' < img src="..." > ');

If you want to preload your pictures, I would put some images into some very small div aside somewhere. If you put pictures into a hidden container some browsers wont preload them.

In case you stored your pictures into some database or memcache, use caching-headers. You might program some outputpicture.php?id=12345. 
In that case something like

```
header('Content-Type: '.get_img_type($data));
header('Content-Length: '.strlen($data));
header("Pragma: public");
$expires = 60*60*24*14;
header("Cache-Control: maxage=".$expires);
header("Last-Modified: Mon, 26 Jul 1984 05:00:00 GMT");
header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()+$expires) . ' GMT');
```

could help alot.

Answer (score 0):

you can add your get address in javascript object , and map the content loaded to it, every time you make ajax request.
then when user clicks on the image, instead of sending an ajax request, first check if you have that request in the object to load it from there, if you haven't the address in the object then you can proceed and send an ajax request and save its result to the object I mentioned.